# Notice:undefined variable

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

Hope everyone is fine over there :)

Actually I am getting the multiple errors of undefined variable but code seems perfectly alright. I am getting this problem again and again in my scripts and I am really fed up from it. It delays my work.

Please check the code and send any solution please. 
Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Here is my code for    *manage-learning-material.php*

```
<?php include("../includes/config.php"); ?>
<?php

if ($_SESSION["isteacher"])
{

$con=mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }

mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
$courseid=$_GET["id"];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM courses WHERE (id='".$courseid."')");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   $id=$row['id'];
   $title = $row['title'];
   $des = $row['description'];
   $subjectid = $row['subjectsid'];
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Manage Learning Material</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2 class="alt">COURSE VIEW </h2>
<?php
if (isset($_GET["status"]))
{
if($_GET["status"]==1)
{
?>
<div class="success">
<?php
echo("<strong>Material has been added in Course Successfully!</strong>");
?>
</div>
<?php
}

if($_GET["status"]==2)
{
?>
<div class="success">
<?php
echo("<strong>Learning Material has been Edited Successfully!</strong>");
?>
</div>
<?php
}
}
?>
<form id="form" method="post" action="manage-learning-material-action.php">
 <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $courseid; ?>" name="id" />
 <label>Course Name:</label><input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="text" value="<?php    echo $title; ?>" /><br /><br />
<label>Choose Subject:</label>
<?php

$con=mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }

mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subjects");

echo "<select name='subjectsid'>\n";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<option value='".$row['id'] . "'";
if ($subjectid==$row['id'])
echo 'selected="selected"';
echo " >" . $row['subjectname'] . "</option>\n";
}
echo "</select>\n";
mysql_close($con);
?>
<br /><br />
<label>Description:</label><br /><textarea name="description" id="description"><?php echo $des; ?  ></textarea><br /> <br />
</form>
</div>
</div>
<?php include("../includes/footer.php"); ?>
</div>
</body>

</html>
<?php
 }
 else
 {
    header("Location: ".$fullpath."login/unauthorized.php");

 }
?>
```

*manage-learning-material-action.php*

```
<?php include("../includes/config.php");?>
<?php
$id=$_POST["id"];
$title=$_POST["title"];
$des=$_POST["description"];
$subjectid=$_POST["subjectsid"];

$con=mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
mysql_select_db("ombts", $con);
$query=("UPDATE courses SET title='".$title."', description='".$des."', subjectsid='".$subjectid."'      WHERE (id='".$id."')");
$result=mysql_query($query);
if($result){
echo header("Location:manage-courses.php?status=2");
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Error/warnings are:

```
  Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\teacher\manage-learning-material.php on   line 11

<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: title in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\teacher\manage-learning-material.php</b> on line <b>86</b><br />
 <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: subjectid in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\teacher\manage-  learning-material.php</b> on line <b>102</b><br />
>Literature7</option>
<option value='3'<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: subjectid in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\teacher\manage-learning-  material.php</b> on line <b>102</b><br />
>Management</option>
<option value='7'<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: subjectid in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\teacher\manage-learning-  material.php</b> on line <b>102</b><br />
>Marketing</option>
<option value='5'<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: subjectid in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\teacher\manage-learning-   material.php</b> on line <b>102</b><br />
 >Science</option>
<option value='6'<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: subjectid in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\teacher\manage-learning-  material.php</b> on line <b>102</b><br />
>Science2</option>
<option value='4'<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: subjectid in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\teacher\manage-learning-  material.php</b> on line <b>102</b><br />

<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: des in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\teacher\manage-learning-   material.php</b> on line <b>110</b><br />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fields will be empty if empty theys value in database.
see next code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `courses` WHERE `id` = '".$courseid."'");
if(!$result||mysql_num_rows($result)<1){echo 'empty result';}
else{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo (isset($row['id'])&&!empty($row['id'])) ? $row['id'] : '';
echo'<br>';
echo (isset($row['title'])&&!empty($row['title'])) ? $row['title'] : '';
echo'<br>';
echo (isset($row['description'])&&!empty($row['description'])) ? $row['description'] : '';
echo'<br>';
echo (isset($row['subjectsid'])&&!empty($row['subjectsid'])) ? $row['subjectsid'] : '';
}
}
```

test this code and Enjoy=)

Answer (score 5):

You aren't getting ERRORS, you're getting NOTICES.... in this case, you are echoing the value of $title when $title hasn't been defined... PHP can still run, but it's letting you know that this is something you should fix...

instead of

```
echo $title;
```

use

```
echo (isset($title)) ? $title : '';
```

or define default '' values for these variables you're being warned about before trying to read from the database

And learn how to execute database queries that don't leave you open to SQL injection attacks

Answer (score 3):

Am not sure where to start with your code ...

Your variables are defined here

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   $id=$row['id'];
   $title = $row['title'];
   $des = $row['description'];
   $subjectid = $row['subjectsid'];
}
```

You need to define them first outside while loop

```
$id = "";
$title = "";
$des = "";
$subjectid = "";

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
    // .. bala bla bla
}
```

Secondly the following line is wrong

```
<textarea name="description" id="description"><?php echo $des; ?  ></textarea><br /> <br />
```

it should be

```
 <textarea name="description" id="description"><?php echo $des; ?></textarea><br /> <br />
```

Lastly

FROM PHP DOC on `mysql_***`

> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:

Comment: @Baba u are absolutely rite but the problem is that my project is not in a state to switch from mysql to mysqli or pdo... i really need to make it secure... do u ppl know any other method thats easy to put into my code and make it secure??? i would be tankful  :)

Answer (score 3):

or this:

```
if (isset($row['title'])&&!empty($row['title'])){$title=$row['title'];}else{$title='';}
<textarea name="description" id="description"><?php echo $title; ?></textarea>
```

or

```
<textarea name="description" id="description"><?php echo (isset($row['title'])&&!empty($row['title'])) ? $row['title'] : ''; ?></textarea>
```

or

```
<textarea name="description" id="description"><?php echo (isset($title)&&!empty($title)) ? $title : ''; ?></textarea>
```

Enjoy=)

Comment: thankyou all :)
this thing just removes the notices but its not showing the data... i want data to be already filled but now the fields are empty :(